# Running qt as a thread from another application written in C language

Tags: qt4

I have a query. Can we run a QT application as thread from another process? if we can, anybody can tell me how??? I have an application written in C language. Some how I need to run the Qt application as a thread from that process. This is because I have some values to be passed to Qt application. I am trying to pass these as arguments to Qt application so as to use these arguments in my window.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing your terminology.

In Linux you normally use [fork/exec](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html) to control an external *process*. A thread is an execution context within your own process. With the fork/exec method you can supply command-line arguments and also create `pipe()` handles to capture stdin/stdout.

You could also link in a Qt application directly into your own.

```
extern "C" int foo_main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication app (argc, argv);
    // rest as normal
}
```

You can call foo_main from some thread in your C program and it will work providing you don't muck around with other GUI stuff as well.